# Clustered solution of Hawtio for camel on openshift

Tags: openshift, hawtio

We have a camel application integrated with hawtio and deployed in openshift environment. This application has been scaled into two pod and exposed to the outside world through openshift route.

So through hawtio actuator url, when we changed the camel routes on runtime, it has been reflected on either of the pods and not in both. We are looking for a solution, where we can update the camel route on both the pods through hawtio url.

Anybody faced a similar sort of issue? please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Hawtio online is the solution for OpenShift:
https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio-online

That said, generally it's not recommended to change Camel routes on the fly on each pod. You can instead redeply the changed deployment and then let it replicate the pods on OpenShift.